# How to implement centralized authentication shared by several nextjs projects

Tags: authentication, next.js, jwt

**Idea**

I'm creating the following structure of services: 1 service hosted on domain1.com that shows the 'company' and the set of offered products, and 1 service hosted on service.domain1.com which is one of those products. Think of openai, you have the openai web service and a different chat.openai service for ChatGPT.

I want to create a new independent service for handling login/sign up processes. As the user can log in in the 'company' web, as well as in the chat web app (in the future, users could also log in in the new products that are offered), I don't want to have duplicated code and I decided to have an independent project for authentication (login/sign up).

**Problem**

The problem comes with the authentication token, JWT. I don't know which way is more appropriate to handle this situation.

I've read about returning the generated JWT embedded in the URL, e.g. https://<domain>.com#jwt=TOKEN. However, I am not aware of all the security issues that can arise.

**Question**

What approaches are commonly used in the industry nowadays? What security issues should I consider? Are there alternatives to returning the jwt in the url, for example with cookies?

Thank you for your responses! :)